# Strange String Formatting In Python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, unicode

i have tried to assign some string in string but some invisible character will be added automatically,

Try to run this code and you see its some invisible characters has been added \xe2\x80\x8b.

```
>>> "LIN+{}+5+​{}:EN'".format(str(5), 2526526545852 or '')
"LIN+5+5+\xe2\x80\x8b2526526545852:EN'"
```

So it shoud be simple like,

```
>>>>"LIN+5+5+2526526545852:EN'"
```

Please share suggestions.

Comment: The problem is `\u200` (represented as `\xe2\x80\x8b`) sign (ZERO WIDTH SPACE https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm') here you have version without it `"LIN+{}+5+{}:EN'".format(str(5), 2526526545852 or '') ` .

Comment: The invisible character is not added by formatting. You have it in the format string already.

Comment: Yes, I didn't mention that. Thanks @MisterMiyagi :)

Comment: @Damian thank you so much for your answer, but from a normal eyes i cant see a different between two strings :) how can i know that extra space is there.

Comment: @RohanNayani you cant... thats why Its called "zero width space", also it's not priting character, second source I can link is wikipedia - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space

Comment: @Damian Perfect , thank you again brother , you save my day!

Comment: @RohanNayani then have nice day! :D